# Loading 64-bit OS on my Dell Dimension 9150 - possible?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a Dell Dimension 9150 running Windows XP and Ubuntu 12.04 . Both are 32bit.

Could I load a 64 bit Ubuntu OS ? For instance I am limited to 3.7gb RAM on 32 bit. If I unloaded Windows and ran only Ubuntu, could I use a 64 bit version and would this relly make the machine a 64 bit machine?

Comment: 32 bit processors can access up to 64 Gb ram if they are pae enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is either 32 bit or 64 bit and you can not change that.

You can run 32 bit OS on a 64 bit chip, but you can not run 64 bit OS on a 32 bit chip.

To see if your processor is 64 bit, with linux

```
grep 'lm' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: Info on casing says Pentium 4 HT

Comment: I am not sure but I think that is a 64 bit processor, at any rate you have been given advice on how to check with both linux and windows =)

Answer (score 1):

You have Intel Pentium D which is capable of running 64-bit OS.
So, you should be able to install 64-bit OS assuming you satisfy other requirements.